# GPG error while updating

Tags: 10.04, update-manager, gnupg

I met this error while updating.I read questions and answers about this problem , but the point is **signing key**. It doesn't return signing key!

```
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com lucid Release.gpg [198B]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid/partner Translation-en_US
                ...
                ...
                ...  
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages [380kB]          
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages [14B]      
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages [4,556B]   
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources [118kB]           
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources [14B]       
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages [125kB]      
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources [34.5kB]      
Fetched 12.8MB in 10min 33s (20.3kB/s)                                         
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com lucid Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
```

Comment: similar question today - possibly server issues? http://askubuntu.com/questions/110215/404-errors-in-synaptic-and-reload-does-not-work-too

Comment: @guntbert: What should i have to do if i have an lucid lts Version ? regards John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally , fixed .

I searched in /lib and found an other "libreadline.so.6" and replaced it and problem fixed.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: A similar situation to the problem you experienced has arisen [in this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/232839/i-cant-update-upgrade-and-remove-my-app-from-kubuntu), but I'm having trouble understanding how to apply this solution. Where exactly was the file that you replaced, and where exactly was the file you replaced it with? Thanks for any more details you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get clean` and then run the update command again.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get clean and then run the update command again ,but it doesn't changed .When I enter "gpg" in terminal , it returns:"gpg: symbol lookup error: /usr/local lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC".!?

Comment: It happened when I installed readline6.2.2 for python2.7.2!!

Comment: Try this:sudo apt-get clean 
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old 
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial 
sudo apt-get clean 
sudo apt-get update

Comment: No change...!!?

Answer (score 0):

well... same problem here (ubuntu 12.04 , 64bit). This worked for me:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6 /usr/local/lib/libreadline_problem.so.6
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6.2 /usr/local/lib/libreadline_problem.so.6.2

sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2 /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.6.2

sudo  apt-get update
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following command and add the key manually:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv KEYNAME
```